# Razor views are not updating after changing them in NopCommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, nopcommerce

I am developing a NopCommerce version 4.1 Theme using Visual Studio 2017. Whenever I make a change to a razor view, I have to recompile the Nop.Web project in order to see any of the changes. This makes the development process very slow.  I disabled caching and enabled edit and continue, but the problem persists.  I suspect the pages are being compiled, but I can't confirm this.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: You sure it's server cache and not client side cache?

Comment: I disabled it on both.

Comment: @ATL_DEV: I don't see any issue. Tried with a random free theme to add my nop solution, modified view page and refresh the page, change appears!

Comment: Are you running version 4.1? I remeber it worked for previous versions.

Comment: I tried running file watch and the problem persists.

Comment: @ATL_DEV, yes with 4.1, could you please share your theme or code somewhere(git or so) I don't find any issue

Comment: @ATL_DEV, Off topic: just tag replay with `@`so I can able to see your notification

Comment: @Div I can't do that, but is there anything specific I should look for?  I think the views are being compiled, but I can't verify it. How can I find out? Another symptom I have is that I have to restart IIS to enable a plugin.

Comment: @ATL_DEV, Try to add `<RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>` after `TargetFramework` in nop.web project file. *How can I find out?* You can go to debug folder and check if you found view page dll there

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to build the project for `.cshtml` files.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, refresh the browser and it's updated.